# Http request header HTTP_ACCEPT is different when the request originates out of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I noticed that when I initiate the same server request, once from a script tag, and the other from within an iframe, the request header's HTTP_ACCEPT section is different.
These are the html page I run:

Request from within an Iframe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<div align ="center" >
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<iframe src="http://example.com/" width=0 height=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no bordercolor="#000000"></iframe>');
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Request from a script block:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
<div align ="center" >
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://example.com/"></scr' + 'ipt>');
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'd notice that the request headers are different between the 2 requests. While the script request's HTTP_ACCEPT equals "*/*", HTTP_ACCEPT of the request which was generated from an iframe may vary from "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" to "application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*", depending on the browser is't being ran on.

Do you know if this kind of behavior is persistent and what causes it? I realize that this section of the header is being generated automatically by the browser, but I didn't manage to find any information regarding the possible differences between requests from Iframe and from within a script block.

Thank you in advance!